# How to hide the physical path of the images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, path, cakephp-2.0, gravatar

In my application i display the image of user by giving the physical path of the directories like http://www.example.com/user_images/abcdefghijk.jpg

But i dont want to expose this physical path to the external users to access the direct files. 
I want to implement the image retrieval as per the gravtar type image display. How we can do that?

Answer (score 2):

In PHP you can use GD library to read the image. So the only way you need to create a image.php file & use the following code,

```
<?php
$imagepath="your image physical path";

$image=imagecreatefromjpeg($imagepath);

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image);
?>
```

this is for jpg image for all other images you can use different functions fo GD library.

So Gravtar.com uses the above way to display the image :)

In ROR you can use Rmagick gem to read the image & display the image with the same way.

Thanks

Comment: Then try to run the file as http://localhost/image.php .. It will show the image, without physical directory path :)

Answer (score 0):

in php you can save a variable in session and append it to image's path like

```
<img src="php_function.php?token=1234" />
```

and in php file get the image reading from session its actual path and return the content by `file_get_contents`

here is the source http://hashmode.com/hide-image-path-php/9